# gdb call function - how to use std::cout as parameter?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>      

using namespace std;

namespace ns
{           
    class D 
    {
        int n;

        public:
        D(int _n):n(_n){}

        void dump(ostream &os);
    };
};

void
ns::D::dump(ostream &os)
{
    os << "n=" << n << std::endl;
}

int main() {

  ns::D d(200);

  return 0;
}
```

In GDB, when I issue the command, `call d.dump(std::cout)`, at the line `return 0;` , I get this gdb error:

```
A syntax error in expression, near `cout)'.
```

Any suggestion how I can pass "std::cout" in gdb calling function?

**[UPDATE]**
Actually it is because of gdb, I was using 7.2; after I switch to 7.11.1, it works fine.

Comment: What versions of `g++` and of `gdb` ? What compilation flags?

Comment: gdb is not really very good at full C++ support, and I don't really expect it to. In order to do something like this, gdb has to be, pretty much, a C++ compiler of its own, and understand core aspects of the language like type conversions, and inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
```

I soon realized, that the debugger does not see `std::cout` symbol at all, probably because it is not used in your code. So I changed the main function as follows:

```
int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
  ns::D d(200);
  return 0;
}
```

And now when I run the debugger, I can perform your call without a problem:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400955: file main.cpp, line 24.
(gdb) run
Starting program: gdb_cout/main

Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cpp:24
24      int main() {
(gdb) next
25        std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
(gdb) next
Hello world!
26        ns::D d(200);
(gdb) next
27        return 0;
(gdb) call d.dump(std::cout)
n=200
(gdb)
```