# What is clang++ option so that inside GDB I can use std::cout as function parameter

Tags: c++, gdb, clang, clang++

I first asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423424/gdb-call-function-how-to-use-stdcout-as-parameter). Now I encounter the same problem when using clang, hence ask again.

I tried both clang++ 3.8 and 3.9, the command options are "-g -O0".

The gdb version is 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class D
{
    int n;

    public:
    D(int _n):n(_n){}

    void dump(ostream &os);
};

void
D::dump(ostream &os)
{
    os << "n=" << n << std::endl;
}

int main() {

  D d(200);

  std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

When it runs to "return 0", call command fails:

```
(gdb) call d.dump(std::cout)
A syntax error in expression, near `)'.
```

The same code and same gdb command work fine when compiled with g++ with same option.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of a verison problem . The program is working fine. I executed it

```
     ~/c++practise> g++ stackoverflow1.cpp
     ~/c++practise> ./a.out
     hello
     ~/c++practise> gdb --version
     GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-90.el6)
     g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)

Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
(gdb) b std::cout
"std::cout" is not a function
(gdb) b D::dump(ostream &os)
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400865: file stackoverflow1.cpp, line 15.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 2 at 0x4008a2: file stackoverflow1.cpp, line 19.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/e1211797/c++practise/outputtrail

Breakpoint 2, main () at stackoverflow1.cpp:19
19        D d(200);
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 libstdc++-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64
(gdb) s
D::D (this=0x7fffffffe0a0, _n=200) at stackoverflow1.cpp:8
8           D(int _n):n(_n){}
(gdb) s
main () at stackoverflow1.cpp:21
21        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
(gdb) s
hello
22        return 0;
(gdb) s
23      }
(gdb) s
0x0000003788c1ed1d in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) s
Single stepping until exit from function __libc_start_main,
which has no line number information.

Program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

Comment: This does not answer why `(gdb) call d.dump(std::cout)` fails.

Comment: Still does not answer the question at all.

Comment: please read the statement of my answer . it is beacuse of the version of gdb that is creating the problem .

Comment: there were lot of problems faced because of the gdb version 7.2 against lcang : u can also refere links http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/How-to-debug-a-code-compiled-by-clang-td4025921.html